# Core-Plot DataLabel Z-Ordering

Tags: ios, plot, core-plot

I try to add data labels to a bar graph in Core-Plot (on iOS). The user selects individual plots and then the values are shown.

The main problem is shown in the image, the other plots overdraw the data labels.

[image: Image showing the problem]

Is it possible to have the labels always at the top?

As the user sets the ordering of the bars, I cannot reorder the bars. (Also if I did, the user experience would be terrible as the whole graph appearance would change on selection.)

Other possibility: Can I reorder the plots for Z-ordering but have the positions remain unchanged?

Any other ideas? I also tried CPTPlotSpaceAnnotations, but I cannot align them on the bar precise enough (see the "1037" label at the year (x-axis) 1980).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution by myself: I just remove the plot and add it back. In that way the plot is raised in the z-Hierarchy.

```
[self.graph removePlot:plot];
[self.graph addPlot:plot];
```